# PHP Iterate through all possible combinations of three dealt cards with dead cards

Tags: php, combinations, permutation

I want to go through all combinations of three dealt playing cards taking into account two (or possibly more) dead cards that can't appear. So with two dead cards for example 5 and 2 I would iterate through all the possible combinations of the remaining cards:

```
2 2 2
2 2 3
```

etc all the way up to

```
12 13 13
12 13 14
```

etc

Obviously there is no need for for example 2 2 4 and 4 2 2 since these would be the same with regard to playing cards. I've checked through many similar questions on here without finding the solution to this specific problem.

EDIT: I realise I didn't ask an actual question: how do I achieve this?

Comment: it's good to see some effort on your behalf towards solving the problem but it seems there is no question here - just a statement of intent.

Comment: Ok I thought people could guess that I want to know how to do this. Ok edited to add an actual question, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39766177/php-poker-algorithm-that-creates-all-possible-poker-combinations

Comment: That's all combinations for two cards. This is you start with two cards and then go through all the combinations of three dealt cards with the first two cards removed from the pack. The dead card part is what makes it more difficult. A permutation of three cards is also quite different from two. Not really sure what question is about to be honest...what poker hands can be made with just two cards anyway??